# Resize a TableView of a TableViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

I have a UITableviewController created with storyboard. Now i want to change the X and Y coordinates of the table view (specifically i want to put a little bit down the table view). There's an option in storyboard where i can set this parameter or change the tableview size? I can't find it

I've tried looking in the size inspector but it looks like X and Y parameter are disabled.

Comment: There is no way to change the X or Y position in the StoryBoard. You should do it in the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tableview of UITableViewController is main view so we cannot adjust it in storyboard . If u want adjust size try this. In your UITableViewController .

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
}
```

It is **`viewDidAppear`** not `viewWillAppear`

Comment: when you trigger a push by clicking a cell, the 'y' get reset to 0.  what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to drag a UIView to the UITableView. This will create a panel where you can add components and will make the UITableView go down. however, the UIView will also scroll down along with the table cells.

Another option is to create a UIViewController. Drag into it a UITableView. In this way, the tableview is fully resizable.

Comment: Drag a new UIView before the default UITableView was the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIViewController with a Container View. Link the UITableViewController to the container. Now you can resize the table view by resizing the container.